# Excel DB: Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: java, database, excel, jdbc

for a jdbc program, im required to make a connection an excel database. the connection is successfully made but wen entering values into it, its giving an "Operation must use an updateable query" exception.

here s the code:

```
        String url="jdbc:odbc:Sample";   //CHANGE THE DATABASE NAME
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection(url,"","");
        PreparedStatement prepstat = null;
        String insert="INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([AccountID], [ProjectID], [PositionID]) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        prepstat= conn.prepareStatement(insert);
        prepstat.setString(1, accountID);  
        prepstat.setString(2, projectID);
        prepstat.setString(3, positionID);
        prepstat.executeUpdate();   // this is where the exception occurs
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you specifically state that the connection was readwrite in your connection string?

I am not familiar with JDBC, but ODBC would be:

```
"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" & _
"DBQ=C:\MyFolder\MyWorkbook.xls; ReadOnly=False;"
```

Excel is read-only by default: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Comment: @amalbose I have added a note that I hope will help.

Answer (score 0):

It was just needed to uncheck the read only while creating the DSN.