# Inserting a row into Excel Spreadsheet via C# and OleDb

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need to programmatically insert a row into an Excel Spreadsheet multiple times. I need to *actually insert a new row* and not insert data, that is, I need to actually shift all other rows down by one.

I am currently using OleDB to insert the data itself like so:

```
//Note I have missed some code out for simplicities sake, this all works fine however
OleDbConnection oledbConn = null;

OleDbCommand cmd = null;

OleDbConnection = new OleDbConnection(connString);           
OleDbConnection.Open();

string connString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0; \"", TargetFile);

sting InsertCommand = string.Format("INSERT INTO [{0}${1}:{1}] Values({2})", WorksheetName, Coord, valuestring);

cmd = new OleDbCommand(InsertCommand, oledbConn);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//close etc
```

I want to be able to insert a row in a similar fashion. Is this possible?

Comment: You might want to consider using an external library for manipulating Excel files like http://npoi.codeplex.com/ instead of OleDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>At a glance, you need to specify read write, the default is read only. Perhaps:
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\Docs\Test.xls;" & _
"Mode=ReadWrite;Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=No"""</s>

At a second glance and re comments, I think [Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8944187/inserting-a-row-into-excel-spreadsheet-via-c-sharp-and-oledb/8945061#8945061) might be the best bet.

Comment: Cheers, Actually, I can write fine, the problem is I need to insert a row rather than adding data to existing ones.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get what you mean. I though I was referring to inserting a new row ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5027899/excel-db-operation-must-use-an-updateable-query/5027963#5027963 )

Comment: Sorry, I am not articulating this very well. The code I provided works fine, my connection string allows me to read/write when inserting data. I need to add a row, shift all existing rows/content downwards.

Comment: @Damien Ah, sorry! I do not think ODBC is going to work for you, I think you will need interop (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111935/c-sharp-and-excel-interop)

Comment: If you want to add that as a answer (use interop) I can accept it. Might make more sense than me accepted this one.

Answer (score 0):

ipavlic is right, you will be better off using an external third-party library for this.  There are several available.  OfficeWriter is one example:

http://www.officewriter.com

Once you open a workbook with OfficeWriter, you can use this method on the Worksheet class to insert rows.  It mimics Excel's behavior, including updating/stretching formulas and other updates:

```
public void InsertRows(int rowNumber, int rowCount)
```